# Not able to use mysql commands in mac after installation

Tags: mysql, macos

I have installed mysql successfully and am at the point where I want to create/show databases. MySQL Server Status says it's running but when I try to run mysql commands from /usr/local/mysql I get the error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   I am trying the command 
>   mysql> SHOW DATABASES

but still encountering this error and have done research to avoid this and came upon using this command to avoid granting permission

> mysqld --skip-grant-tables

after running this command I get another error saying

> mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.13-osx10.11->x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
>   2016-08-16T18:42:00.489762Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT >value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server >option (see documentation for more details).
>   2016-08-16T18:42:00.490049Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for -->secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated >files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path...

I've been going in circles researching error after error and feel that I'm close but just missing one or a few key things. Please help me fix this!

Comment: make sure that the permissions for the installation folders are all correct. Then run MySQLWorkbench to check your settings and confirm that you can connect to the MySQL instance.

Comment: While this is a legitimate problem, it's not programming/code related so it's best answered on [the Superuser site](http://superuser.com) for software support.

Comment: Already reposted on Super User, http://superuser.com/questions/1114288/not-able-to-use-mysql-commands-in-mac-after-installation

Answer (score 0):

**Install MySQL via MAMP (on Mac OSX); once installed:**

Enable file import/export:

1. open "MAMP" use spotlight
2. click "Stop Servers"
3. edit ~/.my.cnf (using vi or your favorite editor) and the following lines:

   $ vi ~/.my.cnf

> ```
> [mysqld_safe]
> [mysqld]
> secure_file_priv="/Users/russian_spy/"
> ```

4. click "Start Servers" (in MAMP window)

**Now check if it works:**

a. start mysql (default MAMP user is root, password is also root)

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

b. in mysql look at the white-listed paths

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /Users/russian_spy/          |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

c. Finally, test by exporting a table `train` into a CSV file

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM train INTO OUTFILE '/Users/russian_spy/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```